# mongo secondary node - weird log entries

Tags: replication, mongodb, network-security

I have mogodb cluster with 4 nodes, all nodes work on standard 27017 port. I found weird things in my `mongod.log` on a secondary node:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:34.593+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn12132","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:42994","connectionId":12132,"connectionCount":143}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:35.065+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn12133","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:43004","connectionId":12133,"connectionCount":142}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:35.106+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn12129","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:41906","connectionId":12129,"connectionCount":141}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.555+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57280","connectionId":12202,"connectionCount":142}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.560+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn12202","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57280","client":"conn12202","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.0.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.4.0-67-generic"},"platform":"CPython 3.9.4.final.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.611+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57296","connectionId":12203,"connectionCount":143}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.612+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn12203","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57296","client":"conn12203","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.0.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.4.0-67-generic"},"platform":"CPython 3.9.4.final.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.755+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57312","connectionId":12204,"connectionCount":144}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.756+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn12204","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57312","client":"conn12204","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.0.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.4.0-67-generic"},"platform":"CPython 3.9.4.final.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.807+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57324","connectionId":12205,"connectionCount":145}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-26T23:22:41.808+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn12205","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"<PRIMARY_IP>:57324","client":"conn12205","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.0.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.4.0-67-generic"},"platform":"CPython 3.9.4.final.0"}}}
```

**I see some weird connections on different ports, and i don't understand what is it. Is it normal?**

---

Servers are protected by `ufw` firewall, but my nodes have full access (on any port) to each other. Port `27017` is opened from outside.

This is `/etc/mongod.conf`, it's the same on all nodes:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/data
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /mnt/data/mongodb.key
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
systemLog:
  path: /mnt/data/mongod.log
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
operationProfiling:
  mode: slowOp
  slowOpThresholdMs: 50
```

`ufw` stauts:

```
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere  
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       <MY_ANOTHER_SERVER_IP>  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       <MY_ANOTHER_SERVER_IP>
Anywhere                   ALLOW       <MY_ANOTHER_SERVER_IP>
Anywhere                   ALLOW       <MY_ANOTHER_SERVER_IP>                    
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)  
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ephimeral ports used by MongoDB:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port